# Langchain model to extract key information from pdf

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain, chatgpt-api, chat-gpt-4

I was looking for a solution to extract **key information** from pdf based on my instruction.

Here's what I've done:

1. Extract the pdf text using ocr
2. Use langchain splitter , CharacterTextSplitter, to split the text into chunks
3. Use Langchain, FAISS, OpenAIEmbedding to extract information based on the instruction

The problems that i faced are:

1. Sometimes the several first items in the doc is being skipped
2. It only returns few items, instead of the whole items, let's say the item is 1000, because of the limitation of chatgpt of returning response, i splitted it into 20 products first, and how can i continue to grab the rest of the products? so i can combine them later.

I am using gpt-3.5-turbo for now.

The goals are:

1. It can return all goods based on what's inside the pdf doc, and the goods could be thousands. (remember there's gpt token limitation for returning response)

My question is:

1. What is the best langchain model or best methods to achieve my goals

(I'm quite new in this langchain world)

This is the code

````
from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter
from langchain_community.vectorstores import faiss
from langchain.chains.question_answering import load_qa_chain
from langchain.chains import (
    StuffDocumentsChain, LLMChain, ConversationalRetrievalChain)
from langchain_core.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI, OpenAIEmbeddings
import os
import sentry_sdk
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from instructions import (GOODS_INSTRUCTION_V2,
                          GOODS_INSTRUCTION_WITH_LIMIT_20_V2)
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, abort
import json
import concurrent.futures
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import pytesseract
import requests
from datetime import datetime
from urllib.parse import unquote
from pathlib import Path
import os
from typing_extensions import Concatenate
from utils import Utils


app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
utils = Utils()
llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo",
                 openai_api_key="abc123", max_tokens=2000)


@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    start_time = datetime.now()

    if 'file' not in request.files:
        return "No file part"

    file = request.files['file']
    if file.filename == '':
        return "No selected file"

    # Save the uploaded file and get its filename
    filename = utils.save_uploaded_file(file)
    embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()

    # Construct expected text file path
    expected_text_file = os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + ".txt"
    expected_text_file = expected_text_file.replace("uploads/", "output/")
    print("Expected text file:", expected_text_file)

    file_size = 0

    if os.path.exists(expected_text_file):
        with open(expected_text_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            extracted_text = file.read()
        print("Text loaded from existing file")
    else:
        # Check file size
        file_size = os.path.getsize(filename)
        # Extract text from the PDF or use OCR if needed
        extracted_text = utils.extract_text_from_pdf_using_ocr(filename)

    text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(
        separator="\n",
        chunk_size=800,
        chunk_overlap=200,
        length_function=len,
    )
    chunks = text_splitter.split_text(extracted_text)
    print("Chunks Length:", len(chunks))

    document_search = faiss.FAISS.from_texts(chunks, embeddings)

    ai_response = start_ai_processing(
        document_search, GOODS_INSTRUCTION_WITH_LIMIT_20_V2, 'gpt-3.5-turbo')

    end_time = datetime.now()

    utils.send_slack_message(
        filename, file_size, start_time, end_time, ai_response, 'gpt-3.5-turbo')

    return jsonify({'data': ai_response})


def start_ai_processing(document_search, instruction, gpt_model='gpt-3.5-turbo'):
    chain = load_qa_chain(llm, chain_type="stuff")
    query = instruction
    docs = document_search.similarity_search(query)
    result = chain.run(input_documents=docs, question=query)
    result = result.replace(
        "```json\n", "").replace("\n```", "").replace("\n", "")
    print("Result:", result)
    parsed_response = json.loads(result)
    
    return parsed_response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=6000, threaded=False)
````

This is the instruction:

```
GOODS_INSTRUCTION_WITH_LIMIT_20_V2 =  ("""
Task: Extract Goods Information from Shipping Invoice and Format as JSON

Objective: Analyze a shipping invoice and exclusively extract the list of goods, 
presenting the details in a structured JSON format with camelCase key names. Maintain the specific document order.

Details to Extract for Each Good:

Product Code,HS Code / Item Code,Product Description,Quantity,Unit Price / Net,Total Price / Extension,Nett Weight,Gross Weight,Total Volume

Extraction and Formatting Instructions:

1.Sequentially retrieve data from the first page to the end.
2.List items exactly as they appear without combining them.
3.For quantity, you can get from total price / unit price
4.Return data in a well-structured JSON format. Any JSON formatting error will result in task failure.
5. Maximum 20 items in the goods list, if there are more than 20 items, just return 20 items and stop processing the rest.

The structure of json should be like this:
{
    "goods": [
        {
            "productCode": "",
            "hsCode": "",
            "productDescription": "",
            "quantity": 0.0,
            "unitPrice": 0.0,
            "totalPrice": 0.0,
            "nettWeight": 0.0,
            "grossWeight": 0.0,
            "totalVolume": 0.0
        }
    ]
}
""")
```

**Any help will be appreciated!**
Thanks

Comment: few things you can inspect. 1. check how the `extracted_text` looks like, does it contain all the content you are expecting? if it is missing, then none of the subsequent flow will have it. 2. `docs = document_search.similarity_search(query)` , does the `docs` results looks okay? if similarly search is not giving quality output then model will not work too. to debug, need complete code with a sample input feed.

Comment: Hi, the result of document_search.similarity_search(query) is not so good, the query is "Commercial Invoice / Invoice". The goal is to look up the page that has Commercial Invoice words on it, but turns out it gives another page too